# jQuery animate() on document.ready

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-hover, document-ready

I am trying to achieve photo zooming effect using this example: http://www.tympanus.net/Tutorials/PhotoZoomOutEffect/ .
However, I needed to make this effect working after **page load**, not on **hover**.
So I changed hover() to ready():

```
    $(function() {
        $('#container img').ready(
            function(){
              var $this = $(this);
              $this.stop().animate({
                  'opacity':'1.0',
                  'height':'200px',
                  'top':'0px',
                  'left':'0px'
              });
           },
           function(){
             var $this = $(this);
             $this.stop().animate({
              'opacity':'0.5',
              'height':'500px',
              'top':'-66.5px',
              'left':'-150px'
             });
           }
        );
    });
```

And then I had the JS error in Chrome debugger:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'display' in undefined
Could someone, please, give me a hint to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful to create a fiddle

Comment: I don't think the `ready` event can be safely bound to anything besides `document`. Try binding to `load` instead (and use a single handler, only `hover` supports two handlers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it like this if you have images with different dimensions

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    img = $('#container img');
    imageWidth = img.outerWidth();
    imageHeight = img.outerHeight();
    centerX = (200 - imageWidth) / 2;
    centerY = (200 - imageHeight) /4;
    img.css({'opacity': 0.5, 'top': centerY, 'left': centerX})
       .animate({'opacity': 1,'height': '200px', 'top': 0, 'left': 0});
});
```

you need to set some values in CSS:

```
#container {
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      overflow: hidden; /*important*/
}
#container img{
    position: relative; /*important*/
}
```